# What should I select for "Export Compliance"?

Tags: core-data, app-store-connect

Today I wanted to upload my app to the App Store, but I don't know which I should select at "Export Compliance" In App-Store-Connect. My App is a To-Do List, which uses CoreData for saving the Data. It doesn't use CloudKit or something like that. The Data is just on the Device. In the App is a Link to my Website and a Share Sheet to share the App with friends. The website isn't a HTTPS its just an HTTP Website. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Export compliance refers to use of encryption in the app, so given your description, you don't appear to use any encryption, so you should be able to simply state that fact when submitting it. You can also avoid answering this question for every build by putting the `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` key in your plist. It would be NO in this case.